# Jbutton performing more action

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jdialog

I have a JDialog where a Jtable is shown, a cell of the JTable is a JButton that open a new JFrame (CoveNew):

```
public void birthstats(String stat) {
    //System.out.println(classeMain);
    String titolo=new String();
    if ("nascite".equals(stat)){
        titolo=lingua_corrente.getString("nascite_title");
        elencojLabel.setText(titolo);
    }
    else{
        titolo=lingua_corrente.getString("anella");
        elencojLabel.setText(titolo);
    }
    Dimension dimensioni = new Dimension(500, 700);
    nascitejDialog.setSize(dimensioni);
    nascitejDialog.setTitle("GesAll 1.0 - " + titolo);
    nascitejDialog.setModal(true);
    hatchlistijTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Num", lingua_corrente.getString("coppiaLabel"), lingua_corrente.getString("annojLabel"), lingua_corrente.getString("jLabel8"), lingua_corrente.getString("NascitaLabel")
        }
    ) {

        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, JButton.class, java.lang.String.class
        };
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            false, false, false, false, false
        };

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    hatchlistijTable.setShowGrid(true);
    hatchlistijTable.setAutoResizeMode(javax.swing.JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    hatchlistijTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setHeaderValue("Num."); //Numero
    hatchlistijTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
    hatchlistijTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(60);
    hatchlistijTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setHeaderValue(lingua_corrente.getString("coppiaLabel")); //coppia
    hatchlistijTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false); 
    hatchlistijTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(50);
    hatchlistijTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setHeaderValue(lingua_corrente.getString("annojLabel")); //anno
    hatchlistijTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false); 
    hatchlistijTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(50);
    hatchlistijTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setHeaderValue(lingua_corrente.getString("jLabel8")); //gabbia
    hatchlistijTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false); 
    hatchlistijTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(50);
    if ("nascite".equals(stat)){
        hatchlistijTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setHeaderValue(lingua_corrente.getString("schiusa")); //data nascita prevista
    }
    else{
        hatchlistijTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setHeaderValue(lingua_corrente.getString("NascitaLabel")); //data nascita
    }
    hatchlistijTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setResizable(false); 
    hatchlistijTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(150);
    hatchlistijTable.setRowHeight(25);
    //hatchlistijTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setHeaderValue("Jump"); //salto
    //hatchlistijTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setResizable(false); 
    //hatchlistijTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(50);
    for (int i=hatchlistijTable.getRowCount()-1;i>=0;i--)
        ((javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel) hatchlistijTable.getModel()).removeRow(i); 
    String qDep = "SELECT d FROM Deposizioni d WHERE d.fecondo=" + '"' + 'S' +'"' +" AND d.morto=" + '"' + 'N' +'"' + " AND d.dataSchiusa is null ORDER by d.dataDeposizione ASC";
    if (!"nascite".equals(stat))
        qDep = "SELECT d FROM Deposizioni d WHERE d.morto=" + '"' + 'N' +'"' + " AND d.anello is null" + " AND d.dataSchiusa is not null ORDER by d.dataSchiusa ASC";

    List depo = DBgateway.getInstance().Run_query(qDep);
    System.out.println(depo.size());
    //Deposizioni dd = (Deposizioni) DBgateway.getInstance().Run_query(qDep);
    for (int i=0;i<depo.size();i++){
        //Deposizioni dd = (Deposizioni) DBgateway.getInstance().Run_query(qDep).get(i);
        Deposizioni dd = (Deposizioni) depo.get(i);
        int toAdd = Program.getConf().getSchiusa();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        if ("nascite".equals(stat)){
            cal.setTime(dd.getDataDeposizione());
        }
        else {
            toAdd = Program.getConf().getAnellare();
            cal.setTime(dd.getDataSchiusa());
        }
        Calendar today=Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, toAdd); // add n days
        //if(today.after(cal)){
        System.out.println(toAdd + " " + today.after(cal) +" " +  "nascite".equals(stat));
        Object [] rowData=getRowData(dd,i, cal,stat);
        if("nascite".equals(stat))
            ((javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel) hatchlistijTable.getModel()).addRow(rowData);
        else
            if(today.after(cal) && !"nascite".equals(stat))
                ((javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel) hatchlistijTable.getModel()).addRow(rowData);
    }
    TableCellRenderer buttonRenderer = new JTableButtonRenderer();
    hatchlistijTable.getColumn(lingua_corrente.getString("jLabel8")).setCellRenderer(buttonRenderer);
    hatchlistijTable.addMouseListener(new JTableButtonMousePriListener(hatchlistijTable));

    nascitejDialog.setVisible(true);
}


private Object[] getRowData(Deposizioni dd,int i, Calendar cal, final String stat) {
    try {
        String qCp="SELECT c FROM Coppie c WHERE c.idCoppia=" + findDatiCova(dd.getIdDeposizione()).getIdCoppia();
        Coppie rCp=(Coppie) DBgateway.getInstance().Run_query(qCp).get(0);
        String data = df.format(cal.getTime());
        //Bottone salto cova
        final JButton jump=new JButton(rCp.getGabbia().toString());
        jump.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        private Object classeMain = this.getClass();
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
           jumpActionPerformed(evt);
            }

        private void jumpActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("jump" +jump.getText().toString());
            String qS ="SELECT c.idCoppia from Coppie c WHERE c.attiva=" + "'"+"S"+"'" + " AND c.gabbia="+jump.getText().toString();
            CoveNew cova = new CoveNew(mainClass, (Integer) DBgateway.getInstance().Run_query(qS).get(0),stat);
            cova.setVisible(true);
            nascitejDialog.setVisible(false);
            mainClass.setVisible(false);
            }
             });
                //

                Object [] rowData = {i+1, // progressivogianluca
                    rCp.getNumeroCoppia(), // numero coppia
                    rCp.getAnno(),
                    //rCp.getGabbia(), // fecondo
                    jump,
                    data};
        return(rowData);
    } catch (IOException ex) { 
        Logger.getLogger(Main_menu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     return null;
   }
}


    private static class JTableButtonMousePriListener extends MouseAdapter {
    private final JTable table;

    public JTableButtonMousePriListener(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
    }
        @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            int column = table.getColumnModel().getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX());
            int row    = e.getY()/table.getRowHeight(); 

            if (row < table.getRowCount() && row >= 0 && column < table.getColumnCount() && column >= 0) {
                Object value = table.getValueAt(row, column);
                if (value instanceof JButton) {
                    ((JButton)value).doClick();
                    //if(((JButton)value).isEnabled())
                      //  anella(row,column);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

The JTable is correctly shown the problem I am experiencing is that when I click on the Jbutton the first time, the new JFrame is shown once, if I click once again it is shown 3 times the 7 and so on. Can you help me to show it only once?
Thanks Gianluca.

Comment: Good Read: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

Comment: Also consider posting [a **Minimal**, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll keep in mind and will try to follow, changing my code, but what about the specific problem? ;-)

Comment: @peeskillet isn't the example readable, maybe not Minimal sorry

Comment: The whole point of the second comment is that I like most people are too lazy or don't have to time to go through a wall of code. So i you follow the instructions of the MCTRE link, and create a **Minimal, Runnable** example replicating the problem, I'm sure most will be more than willing to help. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should not be adding a JButton to the TableModel. JTable uses renderers and editors to display the data.

See [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for an approach that allows you to store text in the column but then uses a custom renderer/editor for that column so it looks and acts like a button. All you need to do is provide an Action for when you click on the cell.

Comment: That's what I tried , but it seems nothing is happening.